# Use SQL LIKE operator in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am building up a query in C#. For integer and string fields, case is quite simple. For date fields, I am using following query:

```
list.Where("myDateColumn >= DateTime(2017,1,20)");
```

How I can perform following SQL LIKE query in LINQ?

```
select * from table where myTextColumn LIKE '%abc%';
```

Comment: use the .Contains

Comment: @monstertjie_za: I want to append like filter in same date filter.

Comment: Do you want to perform a LIKE against a date?  Why not just select where the date is equal to a certain date, and maybe ignore the time part?

Comment: Example folks: list.Where("myDateColumn >= DateTime(2017,1,20) AND myTextColumn LIKE '%abc%' ");

Comment: list.Where(x => x.myDateColumn >= date  && x.myTextColumn.Contains('abc'));

Comment: So there is no way I can specify like query in string?

Comment: The Contains is what you are looking for. It checks to see if the object you are doing the contains against, contains the text you specify, which is essentially the same as what the LIKE does.

Comment: So again there is no way I can specify like query in string?

Comment: No, C# is not SQL. Like @un-lucky has mentioned, you can mix this up with StartWith if you only want to find the words starting with your specified texts, EndsWith only to find words that ends with your text, or Contains for the text anywhere in the word. Do you even know what the Wildcard '%' purpose is in the SQL LIKE clause? Placement of the Wildcard makes a difference, and C# has the methods to back this up

Comment: @monstertjie_za Thanks for your time. Simple answer is there is no way to use LIKE while specifying condition in string.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities for Like in Linq:

> For LIKE '%abc%';

```
list.Where(x => x.myTextColumn.Contains('abc'));
```

> For LIKE 'abc%';

```
list.Where(x => x.myTextColumn.StartWith('abc'));
```

> For LIKE '%abc';

```
list.Where(x => x.myTextColumn.EndsWith('abc'));
```

**Updates :** If you need to add Date comparison as well means you can do like the following:

```
DateTime date2Compare = new DateTime(2017, 1, 20);
list.Where(x => myDateColumn >= date2Compare && x.myTextColumn.Contains('abc'));
```

Comment: I want to append like filter in same date filter.

Comment: @BehzadQureshi: What you are expected the `Like` to do with Date fields? what is the datatype of that column in Database? whats your actual requirement?

Comment: Kindly read comments in question. You will get the idea of actual problem

Comment: @BehzadQureshi: See the updates in my answer: forgive me if I misunderstand the scenario that you ware specified

Comment: Missing: So there is no way I can specify like query in string?

Comment: Could you please make a try on what i suggested. and let me know how the output different from your expected output

Comment: That is a work around and it is already working. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Placement of the Wildcard '%' in a LIKE clause makes a difference, and C# has the methods to back this up.  Below is what the placements of the Wildcard means.

> LIKE '%abc'

**Meaning**: Find any word ending with 'abc'.

**C# equivalent**: `EndsWith`

> LIKE 'abc%'

**Meaning**: Find any word starting with 'abc', and you don't care about the text after.

**C# equivalent**: `StartWith`

> LIKE '%abc%'

**Meaning**: Find any word that contains 'abc', and you don't care where in the word it appears.

**C# equivalent**: `Contains`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) with `myTextColumn` field

```
var date = new DateTime(2017,1,20);
list.Where(x => x.myDateColumn >= date  && x.myTextColumn.Contains('abc'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try solving the problem in *general case*. Suppose we're given something like

```
select ...
 where ... MyField like '%abc%'
```

we can try convert *like* expression into corresponding *regular* one:

```
Like | Description                       |Regular
-------------------------------------------------
   _ | any character  (one and only one) | .
   % | any characters (zero or more)     | .*
```

Implementation

```
// If you want to implement both "*" and "?"
private static String LikeToRegular(String value) {
  return "^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("_", ".").Replace("%", ".*") + "$"; 
}
```

usage:

```
var result list
  .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.myTextColumn, LikeToRegular("%abc%")));
```

you may want to convert the data into `string` before matching:

```
 var result list
  .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.myDate.ToString(), LikeToRegular("%abc%")));
```

Answer (score 2):

While other answers (including the accepted one) are 80% correct, there are some caveats.

T-SQL allows the Like statement to have wildcards not just at the start and end of a string, but also in the middle. And `%` is not the only special char in the syntax, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for details.

.NET Core has `EF.Functions.Like()` method that is literally translated into LIKE statement. See the below example.

```
//assuming there is a db context with a table of Foos
await using var dbContext = new SqlContext();

//assuming table of Foos has Ipsum, Iptum, Ipuum
var result = dbContext.Foos.Where(x
    => EF.Functions.Like(x.Bar, "Ip_um"));
```

Caveats:

- This only works with a server-side evaluation. An attempt to use this feature in client-side evaluation will throw `NotSupportedException`.
- There is a noticeable difference in SQL translation between `EF.Functions.Like` and `Contains` or `StartsWith`, which may [impact performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850629/13640761).

If you are certain you are using server-side evaluation and performance is important, use `EF.Functions.Like`.