# Use Like in Linq query EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the below method in the EF Core application

```
    public List<Prj_Detail> GetByOrg(string org)
    {
        var data = _context.Prj_Details.Where(w => w.Account_Name == org).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

Here instead of `==` I need to check for `Like` how can I do that in my method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like others have said you can do a `Contains` operator however in some cases this casues an unncessary TSQL casting. Instead you could use the in-built Entity Framework functions like so:

```
_context.Prj_Details.Where(EF.Functions.Like(w.Account_Name, org)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8)?

```
var data = _context.Prj_Details.Where(w => w.Account_Name.Contains(org)).ToList();
```

You can use [StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8) and [EndsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netframework-4.8) too.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains) more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Could try with *Contains* to filter.

Please refer the below code.
depending on LeftRim/RightTrim/upperCase/LowerCase

```
    public List<Prj_Detail> GetByOrg(string org)
    {
        var data = _context.Prj_Details.Where(w => w.Account_Name.Contains(org)).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```