# EF Core integer field contains substring efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In a SQL Server database table, I have an integer ID column. This is not a primary key, more like a serial number. I don't have the ability to change the table definition.

I have a requirement that users be able to search for partial IDs. For example, "ID contains '801'".

I can execute the following query directly:

```
select * from items
where item_num like '%801%'
```

In EF Core, I have the following:

```
Items.Where(x => x.ItemNumber.ToString().Contains(idPartString))
```

Which gets translated to:

```
WHERE ((CHARINDEX(@__idPart_2, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [x].[item_num])) > 0) OR (@__idPart_2= N''))
```

Is there a better (more performant) way to achieve this without resorting to raw SQL queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use `Items.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.ItemNumber.ToString(), idPartString);`.

There are few methods in [`DbFunctions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-2.1) class that should leverage SQL operators and functions.

More about how things are translated according to your question in [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains)(not EF Core, but still seems valid).

**UPDATE**

Valuable information added in the comment by [SouthShoreAK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301863/southshoreak).

> Also, using Functions.Like allows you to use wildcards in the middle
>   of the string, which String.Contains does not.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: It appears that both `x => EF.Functions.Like(x.ItemNumber.ToString(), idPartString` and `x => x.ItemNumber.ToString().Contains(idPartString)` resolve to an identical SQL execution plan with the same performance. But, this is more explicit, and answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Also, using `Functions.Like` allows you to use wildcards in the middle of the string, which `String.Contains` does not.

Answer (score 3):

While the first expression is simpler, it's not likely more expensive.  Both require conversion of all the `item_num` values to varchar to perform the comparison.  The first one simply has an implicit conversion, while the second one is explicit.

> If any one of the arguments isn't of character string data type, the
>   SQL Server Database Engine converts it to character string data type,
>   if it's possible.

[LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)