# EF.Functions.Like in a compiled query could not be translated to SQL equivalent

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am writing a compiled query which takes a DBContext and search string as input and returns a list of *Class1*
**It basically runs 3 filters on the class1 objects and returns a filtered list of class1 objects.**

Main query:

```
var temp = await context.Class1.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.param1, $"%{query}%") && c.param2== 1 && c.param3!= 1).OrderBy(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.param1, $"{query}%") ? 0 : 1).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

This actually filters the list and then sorts them in an order where the names starting with the search query are shown before the others.
Then

```
var result = temp.Select(a => new Class2{ T1= a.A1, T2= a.A2, T3= a.A3}).Distinct().Take(10).ToList();
```

Till now this is the Compiled Query I have wrote:

```
private static Func<DbContext, string, IEnumerable<Class1>> Search =
            EF.CompileQuery((DbContext context, string query) =>
            context.Class1
            .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.param1, $"%{query}%") 
             && c.param2== 1 
             && c.param3!= 1)
            );
```

But when this compiled query is called it throws this exception: **the linq expression could not be translated**

How to solve this?

**Update: This is solved now.**

```
private static Func<DbContext, string, IEnumerable<Class2>> Search =
            EF.CompileQuery((DbContextcontext, string query) =>
            context.Class1
            .Where(c => c.param1.ToLower().Contains(query) && c.param2== 1 && c.param3!= 1)
            .OrderBy(p => p.param1.ToLower().StartsWith(query) ? 0 : 1)
            .Select(a => new Class2{ T1 = a.A1, T2 = a.A2, T3 = a.A3 })
            .Take(10).AsNoTracking());
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Can you use c.param1.Contains(query) ?

Comment: am using EF core. I can use c.param1.Contains(query), but then it is case sensitive as well as am not sure if that is much faster in run time

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains/45709434

Comment: If you use the Contains, can you use the StringComparison parameter? There you can define case sensivity.

Comment: Look at the full exception message. It tells you what's wrong, which will give a hint how to fix it.

Comment: @Klamsi No i tried using String.contains(query, StringComparison param), then also the same excep: the linq expression could not be translated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to be hitting yet another EF Core limitation. The problem is not the `EF.Functions.Like` method, but the usage of the interpolated string inside, which as you found works inside regular query, but not inside compiled query definition.

The solution/workaround is to use string concatenation in place of string interpolation:

```
private static Func<DbContext, string, IEnumerable<Class1>> Search =
    EF.CompileQuery((DbContext context, string query) => context.Class1
    .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.param1, "%" + query + "%") // <-- 
     && c.param2== 1 
     && c.param3!= 1)
    );
```

The resulting SQL query is a bit different, but at least you got a translation.

Comment: Okay. So EF core compiled query does not allow usage of the interpolated string with $"{string}" but allows string concat? this was a big learning for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Func<DbContext, string, IEnumerable<Class2>> Search =
            EF.CompileQuery((DbContextcontext, string query) =>
            context.Class1
            .Where(c => c.param1.ToLower().Contains(query) && c.param2== 1 && c.param3!= 1)
            .OrderBy(p => p.param1.ToLower().StartsWith(query) ? 0 : 1)
            .Select(a => new Class2{ T1 = a.A1, T2 = a.A2, T3 = a.A3 })
            .Take(10).AsNoTracking());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `EF Core`, you don't need using  `CompileQuery`, just use `Ef.Function.Like` as below

```
    var users = context.Users.Where(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.FirstName, "%a%")).ToList();
```

So Rewriting your code in this way would be like this:

```
    var result= context.Class1
        .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.param1, $"%{query}%")
         && c.param2 == 1
         && c.param3 != 1).ToList();
```

**Updated**: If you want to get its result as t-sql, you can use `ToQueryString()` like this:

```
  var users = context.Users.Where(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.FirstName, "%a%")).ToQueryString();
```

Comment: What actions are you going to do after getting its compiled?

Comment: oh you mean yeah since compiled query is getting compiled into sql anyway beforehand why would i need EF.Functions.Like to separatelt convert it into sql. Right? i got your point. thanks

Comment: @osmanRahimi The question is about compiled queries, not about whether or not to use them nor about alternatives. Also, `"%a%"` does nothing with the range variable `a`.