# Different performance from SQL Server query from Management Studio vs EF Core 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I wrote a simple EF Core query that makes a select on a table using some where clause to filter data: start date and finish date between the actual date and a field (DescrizioneCommessa) containing a value.

```
        var query = _ctx.Commessas
            .Where(x => (x.DataInizioCommessa.HasValue && x.DataInizioCommessa <= DateTime.Now) || !x.DataInizioCommessa.HasValue)
            .Where(x => (x.DataFineCommessa.HasValue && x.DataFineCommessa >= DateTime.Now) || !x.DataFineCommessa.HasValue)
            .Where(x => x.DescrizioneCommessa.Contains(pattern))
            .OrderBy(x => x.DescrizioneCommessa);
```

To get the raw SQL I just execute the statement:

```
            var sql = facis.ToQueryString();
```

And the resultant query is:

```
DECLARE @__pattern_0 nvarchar(50) = N'COMUNE';

SELECT *
FROM [Commessa] AS [c]
WHERE (([c].[DataInizioCommessa] IS NOT NULL AND [c].[DataInizioCommessa] <= GETDATE()) OR [c].[DataInizioCommessa] IS NULL) 
       AND (([c].[DataFineCommessa] IS NOT NULL AND ([c].[DataFineCommessa] >= GETDATE())) OR [c].[DataFineCommessa] IS NULL)
       AND ((@__pattern_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__pattern_0, [c].[DescrizioneCommessa]) > 0))
ORDER BY [c].[DescrizioneCommessa]
```

I notice that it takes very long to perform the query comparing to its hand-written version:

```
SELECT *
FROM Commessa
WHERE (DescrizioneCommessa LIKE '%COMUNE%') 
      AND (DataInizioCommessa <= GETDATE() OR DataInizioCommessa IS NULL) 
      AND (DataFineCommessa >= GETDATE() OR DataFineCommessa IS NULL);
```

EF Query takes even more than one minute to elaborate, while the normal one is immediate.

I verified that the problem is this part of where clause:

```
   AND ((@__pattern_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__pattern_0, [c].[DescrizioneCommessa]) > 0))
```

If I substitute the above line with:

```
   AND (DescrizioneCommessa LIKE '%COMUNE%')
```

the problem is resolved, the performance is optimal.

Why this line

```
.Where(x => x.DescrizioneCommessa.Contains(pattern))
```

creates this issue?

Comment: ef core 5 or ef6? please don't tag both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behaviour in EF.Core as discussed on SO: [Entity framework EF.Functions.Like vs string.Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708715/1690217)

As a general proposition, `LIKE` expressions do NOT work well with query optimisers. In larger datasets this becomes a serious problem, even though they work just fine in much smaller unoptimized sets. The optimisation is heavily dependent on the pattern being matched and if it is a ranged lookup or not. In your case the pattern cannot make use indexes, EF is simply trying to convert it into an expression that *might* be indexable, in which case after running the expression enough the rest of the database insights engines would advise you to implement an appropriate index.

> Read about some other discussions about parsing String.Contains() to SQL in git hub: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/474

When you explicitly want to use SQL `LIKE`, EF Core added `EF.Functions.Like()`:

- [Like(DbFunctions, String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctionsExtensions_Like_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_)
- [Like-operator in Entity Framework Core 2.0](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-like-operator/)

```cs
var query = _ctx.Commessas
            .Where(x => (x.DataInizioCommessa.HasValue && x.DataInizioCommessa <= DateTime.Now) || !x.DataInizioCommessa.HasValue)
            .Where(x => (x.DataFineCommessa.HasValue && x.DataFineCommessa >= DateTime.Now) || !x.DataFineCommessa.HasValue)
            .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.DescrizioneCommessa, pattern)
            .OrderBy(x => x.DescrizioneCommessa);
```