# Order by best match of string column in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am implementing a search feature for the users in our api. The search will query our db to fetch the first N users matching the search term. I want to order the user after "best match" so the most relevant user is on top.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
var users = await _dbContext.Users
   .IncludeUserData()
   .Where(u => u.Name.Contains(searchTerm))
   .OrderBy(u => u.Name.IndexOf(searchTerm)) <- This row is not possible
   .ToListAsync();
```

Where basically a name that contains the search term early is ordered before a user whose name contains the term late.

E.g.
Simon Carlsson should come before Carl Simonsson if the searchTerm is "Simon"

Using SQL Server as the DB provider

How would I achieve an order by query where users with names better matching the searchTerm are sorted higher up in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching this method of importing functions from the DB provider was found:

```
[DbFunction("CHARINDEX", IsBuiltIn = true)]
public static long CHARINDEX(string substring, string str)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Put this in user dbContext class. It will bind to the CHARINDEX function in SQL Server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Then use it to sort the query:

```
.sortBy(u => DbContext.CHARINDEX(searchTerm, u.name))
```

Comment: so weird this wouldn't already be listed under EF.Functions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LIKE operator?

You may find this useful

[Entity framework EF.Functions.Like vs string.Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains)