# Entity Framework inefficient query

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF and trying generate query with LIKE operator.

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.MobilePhone.Contains(mobilePhone));
```

This block generates this query.

```sql
-- @__mobilePhone_0='42534'
SELECT *
FROM customers AS c
WHERE (@__mobilePhone_0 = '') OR (strpos(c.mobile_phone, @__mobilePhone_0) > 0)
```

i simply want to generate

```sql
-- @__mobilePhone_0='42534'
SELECT *
FROM customers AS c
WHERE c.mobile_phone LIKE '%@__mobilePhone_0%'`
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Like` extension method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-7.0

Use it like this:

```
query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.MobilePhone, $"%{mobilePhone}%"));
```