# Contains in LINQ queries - invalid escape character

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I'm facing the following problem, I have some queries that use `string.Contains` to perform SQL `LIKE` operations inside Linq statements.

Here's an example:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
   query = query.Where(c => c.Field.Contains(value) || c.FieldB.Contains(value) || c.FieldDocuments.Any(d => d.Contains(value)))

 query = query.Include(c => c.Category)
                    .Include(c => c.Headquarters)
                    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Address)
                    .Include(c => c.PhoneNumbers)

var models = await query
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take)
                    .AsSplitQuery()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync();
```

My application is using the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="8.0.0" />
```

But when running this code, I'm getting an error with any input string:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The invalid escape character "" was specified in a LIKE predicate.

Generated SQL:

```
DECLARE @__8__locals1_value_1_rewritten nvarchar(150) = N'ONION';

WHERE (LOWER([b].[Name]) LIKE @__8__locals1_value_1_rewritten ESCAPE N''
```

PS: My ApiContext is in a NuGet package with the models that are shared among our services, it's already on .NET 8 with the same Microsoft.EntityFramework packages versions.

Any tips or insights ?

Comment: I believe your problem might be in the value of `name`. Can you check and verify?

Comment: have yoou check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains ?

Comment: The way this query is written prevents the use of any indexes that cover `Name`. If you have a 100K-row table, the server will have to search all 100K rows for matches. That's why all applications have `Starts With` filters, not `Contains` and never use `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` in the query itself. Use `c.Name.StartsWith(name)`, without trying to change the case. In SQL Server the most common collations are case-*in*sensitive.

Comment: @EvramEhab i tested with several inputs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the tip about perfomance, but my issue is performing is using Contains, remember that this is just a example

Comment: does `name` contains % or other wildcard characters?

Comment: What is the actual generated SQL?

Comment: @siggemannen just simple chars like 'soup', 'onion'.

Comment: @ThomasMendes `String.Contains` *is* the problem, even when it works. The GH issue you linked to has nothing to do with this problem. `String.Contains` is always translated to `LIKE '%blah%'`, which forces a full table scan. The error complains that the actual substring contained an invalid character. You'll have to log the SQL query to see what was actually generated and why this failed.

Comment: @GuruStron 
DECLARE @__8__locals1_value_1_rewritten nvarchar(150) = N'ONION';

WHERE  (LOWER([b].[Name]) LIKE @__8__locals1_value_1_rewritten ESCAPE N''

Comment: @ThomasMendes Please add it to the question (the full text)

Comment: `ESCAPE N''`is the issue, but the question is, why is it empty, it should contain something like \. Maybe some bug

Comment: Such a bug would break all queries that use `String.Contains`. SQL Server doesn't use the backslash for escape sequences either. Something changed the default escape character in this particular case

Comment: What's the actual *full* LINQ query? Does it contain *multiple* `Contains` clauses perhaps? There's a relevant GH issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32432)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hmmm, look like this is the issue, full query updated in question

Comment: This shouldn't happen though. And the escape character shouldn't be *empty*. In the [source code](https://github.com/roji/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerStringMethodTranslator.cs#L90C54-L90C54) the actual escape character is an escaped backslash. Rewriting should only happen [if the pattern contains wildcards](https://github.com/roji/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerStringMethodTranslator.cs#L286). It's as if the SQL query was exported to a source file before execution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos our ApiContext is in a nugetpackage that is shared accross our applications, but the versions of Microsoft.EntityFramework are the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this part of the code seems to be sending empty escape though: https://github.com/roji/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerStringMethodTranslator.cs#L297

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i opened an issue for investigation: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32798