Transform DateTime field to provided format in where clause
I'm trying to integrate a search function in my datatable in Asp.Net Core. I load the content dynamically with a query to my MSSQL server. As the database table content will increase drastically over time I'd like to "preselect" the page result, by applying all filters directly onto the sql command (rather than using AsEnumerable and doing this on client side).
But I've ran into a problem with my datetime field (actually datetime2(7)). In my view I display this value as "ShortDateFormat <HH:mm:ss> created by admin" so for example "12/11/2024 02:40:20 created by admin".
Now I implemented a search bar and would like the entry to show up if I type "12/11" in it, but this doesn't happen.
I used this query for that:
string searchValue;
string localizedText = null; // Doesn't matter how this is filled for this problem.
IQueryable<Entity> query = Entities.Where(x => x.CreateDate.ToString() + " " + localizedText).ToLower().Contains(searchValue));

Unfortunately it seems like my client and the server use different date formats as when I search for "2024-" the entry does shows up. The ToString() method doesn't seem to support the date format parameter here, so how can I convert my server format to the format the client uses? I don't know the client format at compile time though and this should support multiple languages so I'm unsure how I can do this.
Technically I used .ToShortDateString for the view, but at least in my language it matches the  <HH:mm:ss>" format so it should theoretically work. I've given up on trying to use ShortDateFormat for my query as it results in the same error as providing a format in ToString() that it could not be translated.

You say "View" do you mean a SqlServer View so the string "12/11/2024 02:40:20 created by admin" is created within the database?

maybe ef.like is worth a try here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains

@Ralf No my Asp.Net Core cshtml view. My website basically. I execute the query (with the search value) then transform the result in my JSON object with the desired format and then display it. The database just provides its normal values to my controller, which then takes action for the transformation.

Then why do you need to filter (Where) on that generated string? Can't you just filter on CreateDate as Date and presumably some User field so prevent running in any formatting issues? Formatting is a problem of something transformed to a string. A Date field does not have that.

I think the problem here is that you're trying to do a lexical filter / search on a column that is of type datetime. I'd recommend to split the GridColumn into a CreatedOn (Date(Time)) Column and a CreatedBy (string) Column, so you can work with the proper types.

i think OP wants to do something like: select * from sometable where convert(varchar(30), somedatefield, someStyleMatchingClientDate) like '%inputdate%'. This is probably possible by why work harder than necessary? Use a fixed date format on server side, like yyyymmdd and change the search string into something that eventually matches that format. A small disclaimer is that i don't know how to do yyymmdd conversion on EF Core side but it's probably possible

@Ralf I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The UI shows something like 12/11/2024 and obviously if you type "12/" in the search bar it should show up, but that is not, how it appears to be in the query comparision (based on that using the "2024-x" format works).

Ok so you aren't interesting if that 12 might mean day, month or year or is even part of the username? You might want to just call ToString with a fixed culture then. And hope that all of your user have the same notion on how a date should look.

Yeah, where the match in this transformed field is doesn't matter to me, although obviously I have to respect the culture that the user uses for an accured comparision as something like "12/12" as a search text may work in en-US but not other onces, but the client culture should define how this comparison has to be done. Using a fixed format isn't an option as I'm restricted to the UI format of "ShortDateString + :hh:mm:ss". If the culture of the client is en-US then it should be checked if the search string would fit in the date (+ extra text) of that particular localization.

Then you need to get the clients culture setting somehow and use that.

Yeah, but that "use" is the problem here. I can actually get the client culture (including its date formats) via CultureInfo. But I don't know how I can use this in my sql query then to transform the datetime field. I can't provide it to my DateTime via ToString() as ToString with parameter is not supported by EF.

You presumably need to surface the build-in FORMAT function from Sql Server. Does not seem to be surfaced via EF.Functions already. I just found an old example (for non-core EF) that shows how to get and use that. Hopeful someone here knows a more current solution for EF Core (ther should be but i just didn't find any).

@Ralf You're a life save thank you very much. I got it to work via the "built-in FORMAT" implementation. There are probably a few nuances in this implementation as well, but as far as I can see it, it work like I want.

Please post your solution as an answer for better visibility. You can also accept the answer and people can vote for it.

@GertArnold Done (have to wait a day for accepting though).

Thanks to Ralf I found the Built-In "FORMAT" method from SQL and an implementation that seems to solve my issue:
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    [DbFunction(IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string FORMAT(DateTime value, string formatType, string culture)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException("Do not call this directly");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDbFunction(typeof(AppContext)
            .GetRuntimeMethod("FORMAT", [typeof(DateTime), typeof(string), typeof(string)]));
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

and then my query:
string culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
string datePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
Entities.Where(x => (ApplicationContext.FORMAT(x.CreateDate, datePattern, culture) + " " + localizedText).Contains(searchValue);

There is likely a cleaner and better way to write this, but for the moment it is sufficient.

It may be useful to have this db function, but note that the result is not sargable. David's solution is.

@GertArnold The problem here, as Ralph pointed out is that I'd like to implement this as a full search where the input can be at an arbitrary point inside the field. Not to mention that my result is not sargable anyways as I use .Contains(searchValue) for my other fields (which are not shown here) which translates to LIKE %searchValue% which is as far as I understand it not sargable either.

In your code translate the filter expression "12/11" to a pair of dates to use in the query.  Then add criteria for Date>=beginDate and Date<endDate.

What if he searches for "2/1" and wants to find "12/11/2024"? That how i understood why he wants it the way he does it now.
